# Can't get a php variable into a JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

im trying to give a php variable to JS. The script has to give the gps coordinates to a hidden form, which is named after a php variable,and after the click button is pressed it would have to show the information.
If i write  e.g. "latitude3" to the JS script it does work, but with the php var it wont.

Please help me!:) Thank you!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <script>
var x=document.getElementById("log");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="GPS szolgáltatás nem müködik ezen a böngészőn, kérlek értesítsd a rendszergazdát!";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     document.getElementById(<?php echo $longitudee;?>).value = longitude; 
     document.getElementById(<?php echo $latitudee;?>).value = latitude;
  }
</script>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ido" value="Click" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name= "longitude" id="longitude3">
    <input type= "hidden" name ="latitude" id="latitude3">
    </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["ido"])) {
    $g=3;
    $longitudee="longitude$g";
    $latitudee="latitude$g";
    echo "<script>getLocation();</script>";
        $latitude=$_POST["latitude"];
        $longitude=$_POST["longitude"];
        print_r($_POST);
        }

?>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the php variables before you've set them?

Comment: Able to upload a girl's picture. Unable to realise that you can't use variables before you declare them. Go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["ido"])) {
    $g=3;
    $longitudee="longitude$g";
    $latitudee="latitude$g";
    echo "<script>getLocation();</script>";
        $latitude=$_POST["latitude"];
        $longitude=$_POST["longitude"];
        print_r($_POST);
        }

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <script>
var x=document.getElementById("log");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="GPS szolgáltatás nem müködik ezen a böngészőn, kérlek értesítsd a rendszergazdát!";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     document.getElementById("<?php echo $longitudee;?>").value = longitude; 
     document.getElementById("<?php echo $latitudee;?>").value = latitude;
  }
</script>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ido" value="Click" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name= "longitude" id="longitude3">
    <input type= "hidden" name ="latitude" id="latitude3">
    </form>


</html>
```

Move your PHP to the top and add double quotes to the `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

The variables is not declared, until further down the code. You can rearrange the code like this, and it should have the intended effect.

You should also add quotes around the getElementById argument.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["ido"])) {
$g=3;
$longitudee="longitude$g";
$latitudee="latitude$g";
}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <script>
var x=document.getElementById("log");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="GPS szolgáltatás nem müködik ezen a böngészőn, kérlek értesítsd a rendszergazdát!";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     document.getElementById("<?php echo $longitudee;?>").value = longitude; 
     document.getElementById("<?php echo $latitudee;?>").value = latitude;
  }
</script>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ido" value="Click" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name= "longitude" id="longitude3">
    <input type= "hidden" name ="latitude" id="latitude3">
    </form>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["ido"])){
    echo "<script>getLocation();</script>";
    $latitude=$_POST["latitude"];
    $longitude=$_POST["longitude"];
    print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't comment yet so i post it here as an answer:

1. If i see it correctly, you want to get the geolocation of the "navigator" and use this in PHP somewhere?

   As the "getLocation()" javascript is only called AFTER you post the form, you would have to post the form twice to even get the $latitude and $longitude variables filled.
2. If you just want to display the users current location after he/she clicks on the "Click" button, a javascript only solution could suffice.

Since the question is "how do i get a PHP variable into JS", i assume the first (although you could mean "the value of a PHP variable")

To keep your output the same, just (as others already mention) make sure the variables are defined.

```
<?php
    $g=3;
    $longitudee="longitude$g";
    $latitudee="latitude$g";
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <script>
var x=document.getElementById("log");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="GPS szolgáltatás nem müködik ezen a böngészőn, kérlek értesítsd a rendszergazdát!";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     document.getElementById("<?php echo $longitudee;?>").value = longitude; 
     document.getElementById("<?php echo $latitudee;?>").value = latitude;
  }
</script>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ido" value="Click" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name= "longitude" id="longitude3">
    <input type= "hidden" name ="latitude" id="latitude3">
    </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["ido"])) {
    echo "<script>getLocation();</script>";
        $latitude=$_POST["latitude"];
        $longitude=$_POST["longitude"];
        print_r($_POST);
        }

?>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, i would like the first option, without double click.I have to store that in a mysql database, and doublie clicking could not be an option

Comment: Then the echo "<script>getLocation();</script>"; should always fire and not only when the form is posted. Meaning you have to remove the "echo" and just add it directly below the form